# Solve the equation $3\cot(x) + {\sqrt 3} = 0$ for solutions in $[0,2\pi]$

Tags: trigonometry

$$3\cot(x) + {\sqrt 3} = 0$$

$$\cot(x) = \frac{\sqrt 3}{3}$$

I cant find anywhere on the circle where $\cot$ (adjacent/hypotenuse) would be  $\sqrt 3/3$

I can change simplify it to  $\sqrt 3/3$ but that would make the hypotenuse ${\sqrt 3}$ which I can not figure out.

Comment: Adjacent/hypotenuse is cosine, but here you have an equation with cotangent, which is adjacent/opposite side, or if you prefer, $$\cot x=\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}$$

Comment: Also, you've lost a minus sign. You need to find the (2) solutions of $\tan x = -\sqrt 3$

Comment: Ignoring the negative sign for a moment: since the cotangent of an angle is (adjacent / opposite), just draw an angle in a right triangle where the adjacent side has length $\sqrt3$ and the opposite side has length $3$. What is the length of the hypotenuse? What is the cosine (say) of the angle you drew? Does that tell you what the angle is?

Answer (score 1):

Solving for $\cot x$ yields
\begin{align*}
3\cot x + \sqrt{3} & = 0\\
3\cot x & = -\sqrt{3}\\
\cot x & = -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}\\
\cot x & = -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{3} \cdot \sqrt{3}}\\
\cot x & = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}
\end{align*}
In your attempt, you made a sign error in the second step.  If we divide the numerator and denominator of the fraction by $2$, we obtain
$$\cot x = -\frac{\dfrac{1}{2}}{\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}} = \frac{-\dfrac{1}{2}}{\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}} = \frac{\dfrac{1}{2}}{-\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}$$
Since 
$$\cot x = \frac{\cos x}{\sin x}$$
we have 
$$\frac{\cos x}{\sin x} = \frac{-\dfrac{1}{2}}{\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}} \tag{1}$$
or 
$$\frac{\cos x}{\sin x} = \frac{\dfrac{1}{2}}{-\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}} \tag{2}$$
Equating numerators and denominators in equation 1 yields $\cos x = -1/2$ and $\sin x = \sqrt{3}/2$.  If $\cos x = -1/2$ and $\sin x = \sqrt{3}/2$, then $x$ is a second quadrant angle whose terminal side passes through the point $(-1/2, \sqrt{3}/2)$.  The only such angle in the interval $[0, 2\pi]$ is

> $$\frac{5\pi}{6}$$

Equating numerators and denominators in equation 2 yields $\cos x = 1/2$ and $\sin x = -\sqrt{3}/2$.   If $\cos x = 1/2$ and $\sin x = -\sqrt{3}/2$, then $x$ is a fourth quadrant angle whose terminal side passes through the point $(1/2, -\sqrt{3}/2)$.  The only such angle in the interval $[0, 2\pi]$ is

> $$\frac{11\pi}{6}$$